# google chrome sécurity with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, security, selenium-chromedriver

I am coding a small script that would allow me to automatically log in to my google account with python/selenium and chrome driver , but I have a security problem. here are my screenshots. Do you have a solution ? what process should I use? (javascript is actived, i have a good version of chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Google Support page states that sign in via browsers that "Use automation testing frameworks" is being disabled for the following security reasons and Google advices to do "Sign in with Google" using browser-based OAuth 2.0 authentication service.

As some websites, like stackoverflow.com allow you to sign in to their services using "Sign in with Google" it must happen via Google OAuth 2.0 authentication. This implicates that doing so you are also indirectly signing in to your Google account and therefore you can use all the Google services.